# django rest framework override save() method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I override the save() method, the create() method is called inside, but when I add a read-only field uuid, the field is not serialized.
**serializer.py**

```py
class AwsUploadFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extract_file_name = serializers.CharField(source='extract_file.name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ExtractAWSFile
        fields = [
            'uuid',
            'extract_file',
            'extract_file_name'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'extract_file': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance: ExtractAWSFile = super().create(self.validated_data)
        res = upload_file_to_aws(instance.extract_file.path)
        if not res:
            instance.extract_file.delete()
            instance.delete()
        return instance
```

**response**

```json
{
    "extract_file_name": "tets3.jpg"
}
```

So I'm trying to call the save() method of the parent class so that the uuid field can be serialized, but there is something wrong with the file name field I wrote earlier and it will take the path with it instead of just displaying the name.
**serializer.py**

```py
class AwsUploadFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extract_file_name = serializers.CharField(source='extract_file.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ExtractAWSFile
        fields = [
            'uuid',
            'extract_file',
            'extract_file_name'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'extract_file': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(**kwargs)
        res = upload_file_to_aws(instance.extract_file.path)
        if not res:
            instance.extract_file.delete()
            instance.delete()
        return instance
```

**response**

```json
{
    "uuid": "c4aea74e-3748-4c05-8d6c-2413b1eebcc6",
    "extract_file_name": "extractAWS/2022/10/08/tets3.jpg"
}
```

Why is that? I'm wondering what I should do after save() to properly display the uuid field

Answer (score -1):

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
        res = upload_file_to_aws(instance.extract_file.path)
        if not res:
            instance.extract_file.delete()
            instance.delete()
            
        instance = super().save(**kwargs) #call the save method end of your code
```

Comment: However, the upload_file_to_aws method will use the generated instance, so it will not get the instance